# Select and change value of a node from ubl-tr xml

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I want to selct and change value of a node of the below xml in c#. This is a ubl-tr xml sample. Suppose that, I want to change the value of cbc:UUID.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="general.xslt"?>
<Invoice xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2 ../xsdrt/maindoc/UBL-Invoice-2.1.xsd" 
xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" 
xmlns:n4="http://www.altova.com/samplexml/other-namespace" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" 
xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" 
xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2">
  <ext:UBLExtensions>
    <ext:UBLExtension>
      <ext:ExtensionContent>
        <n4:auto-generated_for_wildcard/>
      </ext:ExtensionContent>
    </ext:UBLExtension>
  </ext:UBLExtensions>
  <cbc:UBLVersionID>2.1</cbc:UBLVersionID>
  <cbc:CustomizationID>TR1.2</cbc:CustomizationID>
  <cbc:ProfileID>TEMELFATURA</cbc:ProfileID>
  <cbc:ID>GIB20090000000001</cbc:ID>
  <cbc:CopyIndicator>false</cbc:CopyIndicator>
  <cbc:UUID>F47AC10B-58CC-4372-A567-0E02B2C3D479</cbc:UUID>
  <cbc:IssueDate>2009-01-05</cbc:IssueDate>
  <cbc:IssueTime>14:42:00</cbc:IssueTime>
  <cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>SATIS</cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>
  <cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>TRY</cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>
  <cbc:LineCountNumeric>1</cbc:LineCountNumeric>
</Invoice>
```

Comment: can you please update the sample code for this question?@Mgnfcnt

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution using XML Linq.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement UUID = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "UUID").FirstOrDefault();

            UUID.SetValue("new value");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [UblTr NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UblTr/) to deserialize to invoice object and change value

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(UblTr.MainDoc.InvoiceType));

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path))
{
      var invoice = (UblTr.MainDoc.InvoiceType)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
      invoice.UUID.Value = "new uuid";
}
```